# Get arg types from method signature (mirror/reflection/introspection?)

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to evaluate the signature of a function at compile time. Given a function, I'd like to get the `Type`s out.

For example:

```
func f(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int{
    return 1
}

let y = Mirror(reflecting: f)
let types = y.subjectType
print(types)
```

I get back:

```
"(Int, Int) -> Int"
```

Which is what I need-- in string form! I need them in type form. Intended usage:

```
let unknownA: AnyObject = 1
let unknownA: AnyObject = 2

// The casts (here 'Int') are derived from the mirror above
f(a: Int(unknownA), b: Int(unknownB))
```

EDIT: Ahaha! After what seems like a full day of digging I found [this](http://www.drivenbycode.com/the-missing-apply-function-in-swift/) gem. Will post with a working example when I have it working.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any way to get function parameters type via reflection.

`"\(y.subjectType)"` gives you string representation of function type: `(Int, Int) -> Int`. So you can parse it and get array of argument type names `["Int", "Int"]`:

```
let params = "\(y.subjectType)".componentsSeparatedByString(" -> ")[0]
let paramsTypes = params.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: params.startIndex.successor(), end: params.endIndex.predecessor())).componentsSeparatedByString(", ")
```

I also did not find way to get Swift type from type name but if you have fixed number of types used in your functions, then you can create a dictionary that maps type names to types:

```
let typeMap = ["Int": Int.self]
```

So you can call your function:

```
f(typeMap[paramsTypes[0]](unknownA), b: typeMap[paramsTypes[1]](unknownB))
```

Comment: Thats about as far as I got as well. Handling functions with an arbitrary number of parameters isn't going to go well, but I'll keep at it. Thanks!

Comment: That's pretty creative but we really need real reflection some say is coming with Swift 4.